# reset numeric string value to "1" when it exceeds "9999"

Tags: java, android

How can I reset string number 9999 to 0001, which is limited to 4 digit:

```
String currentNumber = "9999";

String incremented = String.format("%0" + currentNumber.length() + "d",
                Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) + 1);
```

The result above will give me 10000.

Comment: integer string value? what is that supposed to mean? well, what do you think "Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) + 1" does? you have 9999, you add 1 and you return that. add a check of max_value and reset

Comment: `String currentNumber = 9999` - at least post valid java code

Comment: why an integer? a short can fit that ranges better....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulo operator:

```
String currentNumber = "9999";

String incremented = String.format("%0" + currentNumber.length() + "d",
                (Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) + 1) % 9999);
```

And this is how it should look like when you use proper typer for the `currentNumber`:

```
Integer currentNumber = 9999;
Integer moduledNumber = (currentNumber + 1) % 9999;
String incremented = String.format("%0" + currentNumber.toString().length() + "d", moduledNumber);
```

Comment: String currentNumber = 9999 - at least post valid java code

Comment: @ScaryWombat you were right. I fixed code. I will leave a code similar to the original, so that author can easier understand it.

Comment: The problem is that the OP may follow, but some poor sucker who copy-and-pastes your code in the future may not realise.

Comment: I agree on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom method for this

```
String increment(String num, int incrementBy) //incrementBy  is an integer by which you want to increment
{  
    int numInt=Integer.parseInt(num);
    numInt+=incrementBy;

    if (numInt>9999) {
        return String.valueOf(numInt%9999);
    }

    return String.valueOf(numInt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use if statement?
try this

```
if (Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) > Integer.parseInt(maxNumber))
currentNumber = "0001"
```

Hope it will Help you

Comment: you are aware >= is not a good way to compare two Strings, right?